# Cannot change directory from inside a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chdir

I have the following code:

```
module.exports = function(db, threads) {
    var self = this;
    this.tick = function() {
        //process.chdir("AA/BB"); // This line gives error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir"
    }

    this.start = function() {
        process.chdir("AA/BB"); // this works
        console.log("The new working directory is " + process.cwd());
        self.tick(process);
    }
}
```

I call start() from another class like this:

```
var man = require('./temp.js');
var manager = new man(db, threads);
manager.start();
```

Can somebody explain why I can change directory from start(), but not from tick()? Do I need to pass something between these functions?

Thanks.

Comment: in line - self.tick(process);  you are passing a variable process, but "this.tick = function() { "  does not have any parameters.

Comment: I tried adding parameters to the function and using them, it didn't help :( Is this the way to go? Pass process to the function and somehow use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used relative dir path `AA/BB`, by calling `start()` the process has already `chdir`ed to that directory relative to the `cwd`, `./AA/BB`.

Calling `tick()` consequently will make it look up `AA/BB` in the current cwd `./AA/BB`, e.g. `./AA/BB/AA/BB`, which doesn't exists.

Comment: Yes you are right :( I was checking __dirname and it was still pointing to the parent directory, so I assumed that chdir didn't work. __dirname must mean something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this so we could catch some more information about the error

```
 this.tick = function() {
   try {
    console.log('__dirname: ', __dirname);
    console.log("The directory from which node command is called is " + process.cwd());
    process.chdir("root_path/AA/BB");
}
catch (err) {
        //handle the error here
}
}
```

just be sure that you give the correct root path.

./ and process.cwd() refers to the directory on which the node command was called. It does not refer to the directory of the file being executed.

__dirname refers to the directory where the file being executed resides.

So be careful, the next time you use ./, process.cwd(), or __dirname. Make sure what you are using is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that __dirname also shows the current directory, that's where I went wrong as I used it for testing.